# Installing IKEA farmhouse sink in 23 inch deep cabinet?

Tags: kitchen-sink

We bought this [IKEA farmhouse sink](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/S59093554/) that I love.

[image]

Unfortunately I found out our kitchen cabinets are only 23 inches deep. The sink is made for standard 24 inch deep cabinets. Any suggestions for installation?

Comment: The front of farmhouse sinks sit forward of the edge of the cabinets. Is there any problem letting it stick out an extra inch?

Comment: How about a pic of the existing cabinet/sink arrangement and a model # for the new sink?

Comment: No I don't have a problem with it sticking out. Just not sure how to support it.

Comment: We are getting new countertops after we figure out how to get the sink to work. Countertop guys said they needed to see how it worked before they cut the countertops.

Comment: http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/S59093554/

Comment: Here is the model http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/S59093554/

Comment: Here is countertop and sink that is there now. IMG_0049.JPG

Comment: You will have to copy the picture to an existing web location so that it can be seen. Someone with higher reputation points can then help to bring it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the sink can be used with a shallower cabinet frame as long as you don't mind more of the sink projecting from the front of the cabinet than what you may have seen when it was displayed in the showroom.

Also, there is a trim board that is usually installed below the sink rim at the front, to hide the bowl. This may not be possible if your cabinet frame does not project out far enough. Your cabinet doors would also need to be installed below the projecting portion of the new sink.

Your "countertop guys" are correct, you should wait until the sink is at the job prior to any alteration of top or cabinet. If you are not handy with cabinet making or carpentry, a good cabinet contractor can likely make this a quality install that looks good too.